# showing that an inequality holds

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, inequality

I am trying to figure out how to show that for $n\geq 3$,
$$(2^n-1)^{\frac{n}{2(n-1)}}\geq (2^{n-1}-1)^{\frac{n-1}{2(n-2)}}+1.$$

I've tried basic algebra and induction, but the inductive hypothesis seems to be useless. I've also tried using calculus, but the derivatives of each side are insane. Any suggestions?? Thanks!

Comment: Try this $$(2^n-1)^{\frac{n}{2(n-1)}}-(2^{n-1}-1)^{\frac{n-1}{2(n-2)}}\geq 1.$$

Comment: Let $f(n) = (2^n-1)^{\frac{n}{2(n-1)}}-n$.  Your inequality is equivalent to $f(n) \geq f(n-1)$.  So showing that the derivative of $f$ is positive for $n \ge 3$, proves the inequality.  Also note that $\dfrac{n}{2(n-1)} = \dfrac12 + \dfrac1{2(n-1)}$

Answer (score 0):

Let $P_n$ be statement (the inequality) which is true for $n \geq 3 $.

Check Base Step: $ P(3)$ Give us $Left Hand Side = 4.30351707066$,
$RHS = 4$ which we can see $P(3)$ is true.

Now we do inductive step, assume that $P(k)$ works. 
$P(k): (2^k -1)^{k/2k-2)} \geq (2^{k-1} -1)^{(k-1)/2(k-2)} +1 $

Then we assume $P(k+1)$ also work which we have
$P(k+1): (2^{k+1} -1)^{(k+1)/2k} \geq (2^{k} -1)^{(k)/2k-2)} +1 $

Here we can see the RHS of $P(k+1)$ looks almost the same as LHS of $P(k)$, so we have inequailty:
$(2^{k+1} -1)^{(k+1)/2k} \geq (2^{k} -1)^{(k)/2k-2)} +1 \geq (2^k -1)^{k/2(k-1)} \geq (2^{k-1} -1)^{(k-1)/2(k-2)} +1  $ add something here to make it look nicer if needed.

which we can see $P(k)$ is true for any $k\geq 3$

Conclusion. $P(n)$ is true for any n bigger or equal to 3.